# Mysql sum function result show in every row

Tags: php, mysql

I've following db structure.

```
id      email     lat      long      point      balance    date
1       33        1.00     2.00      0          empty      date 
2       34        8.00     3.00      -1         empty      date
3       33        7.00     4.00      2          empty      date
4       33        6.00     5.00      0          empty      date
5       33        6.33     5.43      -1         empty      date
```

so i want to show all record which email id is 33 but it's must be show the balance in every row for example.

```
In first row it's balance is 0
second row it's balance is   2
third row it's balance is    2
four row it's balance is     1
```

so my php code is look like this but can't get correct balance:

```
echo "<table width='100%' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='100'><b>Date</b></td>";    
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='100'><b>Lattitude</b></td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='50'><b>Longitude</b>
</td>";                     
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='50'><b>Point</b>
</td>";                     
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='50'><b>Balance</b>
</td>";                     
echo "</tr>";

while($res =  mysql_fetch_array($park_history))
{
    $lat = $res['lat'];
    $long = $res['long'];
    $point =  $res['point'];
    $date = $res['date'];           
    $balance = 0;

$sum = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(point) AS points FROM balance WHERE email = 
'".$_SESSION['SESS_ID']."'");
    $sum_res = mysql_fetch_array($sum);
    $sum = $sum_res['points'];

    echo "<tr>";                
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$date</td>";
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$lat</td>";
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$long</td>";
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$point</td>";
            echo "<td class='tdhead2'    
valign='top'>$sum</td>";                        
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I believe it can be done using mysql sum function. Can you plz give me solutions or suggestions. Thank You.

Comment: In first row it's balance is 0 but how ?

Comment: @samitha because in the db the point is 0 so balance is 0 and then the point is 2 so the balance is 0+2 = 2 and so on..

Comment: What's the problem you have now ?

Comment: it's don't show correct balance in every row.

Comment: oh,, i ever made a program like this. wait please! :D

Comment: @alexmojum your sql is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL `sum` function won't do what you want it to - but it doesn't have to - there's a much easier way to acomplish your task using the result you already fetched.

Since you already have the `$point` for the row you're operating on, simply add that to a counter and proceed from there. As it is, you're making a superfluous db call every row.

Use:

```
$sum = 0;

while ( $res = mysql_fetch_array($park_history) ) {

    /* yada yada */
    $point =  $res['point'];
    $sum += $point;

    echo /* your table here */

}
```

You can completely drop the lines:

```
$sum = mysql_query( ... );
$sum_res = mysql_fetch_array($sum);
$sum = $sum_res['points'];
```

`$total` will hold the running points tally as you described and won't query your db every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the php :

```
$park_history = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM balance 
WHERE email ='".$_SESSION['SESS_ID']."'");
$i = 0;
$balance = 0; // the first sum of balance will 0 + first point
while($res =  mysql_fetch_array($park_history))
{
    $i++;
    $lat    = $res['lat'];
    $long   = $res['long'];
    $point  = $res['point'];
    $date   = $res['date'];           
    $balance= $balance + $point; // balance will be updated in every loops
    echo "<tr>";                
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$date</td>";
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$lat</td>";
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$long</td>";
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$point</td>";
            echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$balance</td>";                        
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I remove this code :

```
$sum = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(point) AS points FROM balance WHERE email = 
'".$_SESSION['SESS_ID']."'");
    $sum_res = mysql_fetch_array($sum);
    $sum = $sum_res['points'];
```

and redefine `$park_history` :

```
$park_history = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM balance 
WHERE email ='".$_SESSION['SESS_ID']."'");
```

just check it out! and tell me (comment) if you find some errors.. may it help :D